# Is there an open source lexer (parser) for the go language?

Tags: go

For the go language, is there a tool that would parse it into lexical elements? I am looking for a filter that would take go source code and output a tokenized version of it. It does not need to do full semantic compilation.

thank you in advance,

Comment: It's just in stdlib: [`go`](https://golang.org/pkg/go/)

Comment: I imagine there's a lexer in the Go compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard Lib:

https://golang.org/pkg/go/

You can start with the [scanner](https://golang.org/pkg/go/scanner/) package, it will tokenize Go source code.

[Example](https://golang.org/pkg/go/scanner/#example_Scanner_Scan)

Comment: Thank you very much. This was enough for me to solve the problem I had.